# Logging into IMAP (Dovecot) server

Tags: authentication, dovecot

I am attempting to login to my IMAP Dovecot server on my Amazon EC2 instance. I am attempting to login as root and I recieve this error in the mail log:

```
dovecot: imap: Error: user root: Invalid settings in userdb: userdb returned 0 as uid
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't login to IMAP as root ($10 says you're not using TLS either, so your root password just went across the Internet en-clair).  Redirect mail destined for the root account to a non-privileged account, collect the mail from that account, change your root password, and setup TLS.

Comment: I figured using root for login would not be a good idea. I am trying to setup the mail handling for the user "postmaster" now which I assume is the default account postfix creates. Have no idea how to setup TLS.

Comment: I can't get postfix to receive mail as a different user other than "root". In the alias file I changed the email alias to "postmaster". I reloading postfix but it still continues to use root@mydomain.com instead of postmaster@mydomain.com

Comment: If you don't know how to do something like setup TLS, ask a question on Server Fault.  Did you run `newaliases` after you edited `/etc/aliases`?  Also, `postmaster` is a "role account" too; you should feed that to a real user account as well.

Comment: Yes I ran newaliases. Should I not use postmaster and make another account? I don't know why it keeps sending to root

Comment: You should already have a regular account on the system for you to use; redirect all the mail to that.  Please don't ask extended questions in comments; reformulate your question into something comprehensive and answerable and ask it as a new question.

Comment: But if I do that you may not find my question.

Comment: You'll have to take that chance, because I'm not answering any more in this comment stream.  You'll get more attention for your questions if you upvote useful answers now and then, though.  <hint><hint><nudge><hint>

Comment: Very theoretical answer, what are the steps to fix? Which files to touch? How to set up redirect etc? It's one of the top Google finds but doesn't say much in detail... yeah, you can google even more but...